# How to concate join condition based on input flag value inside cursor in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have a below SP which has sql query which need to refactor db2 query,in db2 i dont know how to concatenate the flag condition remaining query to main query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EMPLOYEE
(IN EMPID varchar(1000),
IN BFLAG char(3))
RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
P1: BEGIN
SET v_sql = 'select c.id,c.name from emp c'

IF BFLAG <> 'T' THEN
        SET v_sql = v_sql ||
            ' left outer join dept U
            where c.empid in (' || EMPID || ') ';
    ELSE
        SET v_sql = v_sql ||
            ' where c.empid in (' || EMPID || ') ';
END IF;
```

how to concatenate query in db2 based on flag value specified above condition.

DECLARE c_id CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
select c.id,c.name from emp c;

Answer (score 0):

Too many errors.
You should study how the [compound-statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=pl-compound-statement) must be constructed.
Every variable must be declared.
The order of statements inside is significant: variable declarations first, then statements, cursors. *SQL-procedure-statements* are afterwards only.
You get erroneous dynamic statement if `BFLAG <> 'T' is true`: left join without conditions.

If the questions is how to use cursor with dynamic statements, then here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_DYNAMIC (IN P_REST varchar(1000))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE v_sql VARCHAR (1000);
    DECLARE v_s STATEMENT;
    DECLARE v_c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR v_s;
    
    SET v_sql = 'select ' || P_REST;
    PREPARE v_s FROM v_sql;
    OPEN v_c1;
END
@

CALL TEST_DYNAMIC (' * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPNO IN (''000010'', ''000020'')')@
```

If not, then try to compile your routine without errors at least and show the runtime error / unexpected result if any...

Comment: I want to make the above dynamic query to static query. i don't want to use sql variable to set the query.im using cursor but inside cursor how should i validate the condition and join the query is my question.???

Comment: How could this query be static, if it uses different set of tables depending on the parameter value passed? It's not possible. Why do you want namely static sql instead of dynamic one?

Comment: I'm refactoring procedure, dynamic query taking more execution time, The issue is dynamic query having flag value based on that its left joining else right joining. if i make the dynamic to static query by using cursor and temp table logic. I'm storing the user input id's into temp table then joining to the main query. I tried to create the different cursor one cursor has flag true query in it other cursor has flag false query. im opening the cursor based on flag, But the static query execution time is taking more then the dynamic query. Any help or suggestion will be helpfull!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you wrote above. Please, edit your question with CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements for some reproducible example. Provide a number of CALL statements and the result desired for each such a CALL.